# permutation representations of Quantum Ternary Benchmark functions

Tags: state-preparation

I recently studied this paper: http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agra/doc/konf/SAT-based_Exact_Synthesis_of_Ternary_Reversible_Circuits_using_a_Functionally_Complete_Gate_Library.pdf

In this paper the algorithm is evaluated using random permutations for example `F = (5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0, 1, 4)` . And also evaluated using Quantum Ternary Benchmark functions for example mul2.

But there is no data about the same representation of benchmark functions. In other words, i need some `F = (...)` for **mul2** and other Quantum Ternary Benchmark functions to test my own algorithm on them.